# Create a NxN array for all diagonals

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given an integer n, create nxn nummy array such that all of the elements present in both its diagonals are 1 and all others are 0

Input: 4

Output

```
  *[[1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1]]*
```

how do i achieve this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fill_diagonal` to fill the elements in the principal diagonal and use it with `np.fliplr` to fill elements across the other diagonal. Refer [link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html)

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((4, 4), int)
np.fill_diagonal(a, 1)
np.fill_diagonal(np.fliplr(a), 1)
```

**Output :**

```py
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an identity matrix and its flipped view, then take the maximum of the two:

```
np.maximum(np.eye(5, dtype=int), np.fliplr(np.eye(5, dtype=int)))
#array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
#       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Edited: changed `[::-1]` to `np.fliplr` (for better performance).

Comment: I am getting the below output
Out[4]:
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])

Comment: Have you specified the `int` datatype?

Answer (score 0):

I would do (assuming n=5):

```
import numpy as np
d = np.diagflat(np.ones(5,int))
a = d | np.rot90(d)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1]]
```

I harness fact that we could use `|` (binary OR) here for getting same effect as `max`, because arrays holds solely `0`s and `1`s.